# MySQL default value - YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1067

I'm trying to create table with column like

```
model_year smallint(4) not null default YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
```

But there is an error (Invalid default value).
What may I do to set default value for the model_year current year?

Comment: do you expect to have negative years like the year -1989 ? so should that be smallint unsigned not null - think about it. and drop the optional display width specifier (4) as you are not using zerofill !!

Answer (score 3):

From the [MySQL doc pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html) (my bold):

> The `DEFAULT` value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, **the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression**. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`. The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for a `TIMESTAMP` column.

I suspect you'll either have to specify the real value when you insert the row.

---

If you didn't want to do that, you *could* allow NULLs and then periodically sweep the database with another process doing:

```
update table mytable set model_year = year(current_date) where model_year is null
```

but that's a kludge, and rather dangerous to boot, since there will be a period of time where NULLs exist in the column.

That's something all your queries would have to take into account, leading to ugliness like:

```
select a, b, model_year from mytable where model_year is not null
union all
select a, b, year(current_date) from mytable where model_year is null
```

I'd go the non-default route myself.

Comment: One option is to use a default magic value and then set up a trigger which is run AFTER INSERT. This trigger could set the current year.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a stored procedure (sorry, I do not know the MySQL syntax). You can set up a stored procedure that triggers on INSERT or UPDATE that looks for a NULL in the model year column and replaces it with an identical INSERT or UPDATE that sets the model year.